# How to programmatically determine record size in Aerospike

Tags: aerospike

Is there any way to determine the storage size of an Aerospike record programmatically?  Neither client.info or the metadata from get() seem to have it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run-time object storage statistics can be found by doing "info" calls to get object histograms. For example,

asinfo -v 'hist-dump:ns=test;hist=objsz'

See http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/info/#hist-dump

Byte-level storage size can be determine off-line via information http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/plan/capacity/